# ¿Puedo crear una aplicación móvil utilizando el Stack MEAN JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

Me recomendaron usar el stack MEAN, debido a que se me da bien JavaScript. Deseo crear algunas aplicaciones y mi pregunta es:

¿Puedo crear aplicaciones móviles usando MEAN? ¿o es realmente necesario crearlas con Java en Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar MEAN para desarrollar el backend (API REST o servicios web), pero estarías usando solo tres letras del stack (M=MongoDB, E=Expressjs, N=Nodejs) ya que el frontend seria la aplicación móvil y no una web con Angular.
Si deseas una aplicación móvil que puede descargarse desde la PlayStore o AppStore tienes dos opciones:

1. Desarrollar la aplicación web nativa con java o Objective-C/Swift para Android o iOS respectivamente.
2. Usar un framework para desarrollo de aplicaciones móviles híbridas como [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/%20Ionic%20Framework) donde puedas hacer apps usando HTML, CSS y Javascript y luego se compilan con [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) para cada sistema operativo. En el caso de Ionic, usan AngularJS como librería de Javascript y entonces de cierta forma estarías completando el stack MEAN.

En resumen el stack MEAN no te ayudara a hacer una aplicación móvil especificamente, si no mas bien te puede servir como herramienta para construir el backend de una, sin embargo esto puede hacerse con cualquier lenguaje ya que es indiferente para una app debido a que solo tiene que consumir el servicio web que devuelve los datos en un formato común (JSON).

Si eres bueno en Javascript y quieres hacer apps móviles te recomiendo que estudies Ionic Framework o React Native.

Saludos. Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Crea un  API RESTful con **M**ongoDB + **E**xpressJS + **N**odeJS.

Usa NativeScript con la version 2 de **A**ngular. Escribes componentes que se pueden compilar a un APK.

Si, si puedes.